# Magento 2.3.5 violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

I installed the ebay module m2pro but it doesn't work properly due to the magento csp policy, here some screenshot:

[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHAWW.png)

I noticed that 2 scripts are blocked:

[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyPIi.png)

[screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZmkL.png)

[screen 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZmkL.png)

How I can solve this problem without disabling CSP?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add domain to CSP whitelist: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html#add-a-domain-to-the-whitelist

For images you can add this:
`<value id="[ID]" type="host">https://</value>`

All images from https won't be block.

Comment: Thanks, solved by myself creating csp_whitelist.xml